# Am I allowed to give my kippah to a rat?

Tags: kippa-yarmulka, tzaar-baalei-chayyim

I was walking on the sidewalk and noticed a rat shivering on the pavement; it was so cold it couldn’t move and it probably would have died of frostbite if I didn’t do anything. I gave it my kippah for warmth and gently nudged it towards the edge of sidewalk so that no one stepped on it. Was I allowed to do that?

Comment: Did you have any other head-covering at that moment?

Comment: Does your neighborhood have a rat shortage?

Comment: A kippah is not "holy" or "consecrated" or anything like that. It's just a convenient form of a head-covering, as the custom is to use *some* sort of head-covering. Plenty of people have used kippahs when handling a hot lightbulb, or as an oven mitt if necessary. So it's no different whether you covered the rat with a kippah, wool hat, or handkerchief. Whether covering a cold rat is the right thing to do is a totally different question.

Comment: was the rat Jewish?

Comment: I was thinking it could also be bal taschit cuz I’m kinda wasting the kippah

Comment: To fellow reviewers: How can this be a practical ruling if it's in the past? Are we worried that OP will go and start a rat kippa gemach? :)